# How to make subdomain point to a different path without a redirect?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

How can I make `http://param1.domain.com` act as if it's loading `http://domain.com/param1` in Nginx? I do not want to redirect to `http://domain.com/param1`. So far I have created a new server block containing the following:

```
...

server_name param1.domain.com;

...

location / {
    return 301 "http://domain.com/param1${uri}";
}

...
```

but as mentioned above this just redirects the url.

Also, I am using a PHP framework to route using the `param1` and other `$uri` parameters. Is this even possible without a redirect? Ie. I'd like to use something like `http://param1.domain.com/param2` instead of `http://domain.com/param1/param2`

Comment: Could you add a table containing input and expected output, e.g. `mydomain.com` => `mydomain/hellworld`?

Comment: I got around this problem by just installing an additional web directory for my `param1` ("subdomain").